# Why can we consider this Hilbert space transformation as corresponding to this rotation of reference frame?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reference-frames, quantum-spin, rotation

At the outset, let me state what I know. From Chapter 3 of Ballentine (restricting just to rotation transformations since that's all I'm concerned with here) I know that if frame $\mathcal{S}'$ is related to frame $\mathcal{S}$ by a rotation about the $z$-axis by angle $\theta$ (in the standard right-hand rule direction), then given the assignment of state $|\psi \rangle$ to a particular system by an observer in $\mathcal{S}$, an observer in  $\mathcal{S}'$ will assign the state $|\chi \rangle e^{-i\theta J_z/\hbar}|\psi \rangle$.

If the above understanding is correct, then I am tremendously confused about a claim made in Chapter 12.1 of Ballentine. In analyzing a spin-resonance experiment, Ballentine applies $e^{i\omega tJ_z/\hbar}$ (NB the lack of minus sign) to the state ket $|\psi \rangle$ in the original system, and then claims "we have shown that, with respect to a frame of reference rotating along with $\mathbf{B}_1$ at the rate $\omega$...". But hang on, given the lack of minus sign, shouldn't we have transformed ourselves into a frame rotating at $-\omega$ relative to the original frame? What am I missing here.

Below I include the entire discussion from Ballentine if my question here is not clear. The quoted statement comes at the very end of the discussion.

[image]
[image]

The relevant table in Ballentine (Chapter 3) for the homomorphism between spacetime transformations and unitary operators on Hilbert space is as below:
[image]

Comment: reference/link for  Balentine

Comment: @annav My apologies, this is Ballentine's *Quantum Mechanics: A Modern Development*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the author is just being imprecise in his wording.  Rotating at a rate of $\omega$ is the same as rotating at a rate of $-\omega$, just in the opposite direction; both cases can reasonably be considered to be rotating at a rate of $\omega$ if we don't care about specifying the direction of rotation.

Comment: I see, thank you. Just to be sure, do you agree with my interpretation of which frame of reference we are transforming to when applying this unitary operator?

Comment: It can be defined either way; the change in definition would just change the matrix form of $J_z$ written relative to a particular basis.  So just double check chapter 3 of Ballentine to be sure that that is the definition.

Comment: Chapter 3 of Ballentine uses the conventional definition which I noted (I will include the table right now in the OP just so you can see it to confirm).

Comment: Then yeah, I think your interpretation is correct: we are rotating with a frequency of $-\omega$ in order to go from the static frame of reference to the rotating one.

Comment: Super, thank you so much!